# Mosquitto configuration for Websockets + TLS

Tags: ssl, websocket, mqtt, mosquitto

I've been using mosquitto + websockets on debian 8 since a while, with great results. Now I'd like to move the system to pre-production, so I need to start encrypting these communications.

I have tried generating the certificates by hand, following the steps found on this blog post (http://embeddedprog.blogspot.pt/2014/05/tlsssl-communication-via-mqtt.html) and with the certificate generation script from J-P Mens (https://github.com/owntracks/tools)

My "mosquitto.conf" looks like this:

```
allow_anonymous false
allow_duplicate_messages false
autosave_interval 1800
persistence true
persistence_file mosquitto.db
persistence_location /tmp/
connection_messages true
log_timestamp true
#log_dest syslog

#log_type error
#log_type warning
#log_type notice
#log_type information
log_type all
log_type debug


listener 8880
protocol mqtt

listener 8881
protocol websockets
bind_address hi-server
cafile /home/hi/cert/ca.crt
certfile /home/hi/cert/hi.com.crt
keyfile /home/hi/cert/hi.com.key
tls_version tlsv1
#require_certificate false

#
#   __  __       ____   ___  _
#  |  \/  |_   _/ ___| / _ \| |
#  | |\/| | | | \___ \| | | | |
#  | |  | | |_| |___) | |_| | |___
#  |_|  |_|\__, |____/ \__\_\_____|
#          |___/
#
#

#auth_plugin /home/jpm/mosquitto-auth-plug/auth-plug.so
auth_plugin /etc/mosquitto/auth-plug.so
[auth_opt stuff...]
```

And this is the mosquitto verbose output:

```
1448802719: mosquitto version 1.4.2 (build date 2015-11-27 23:40:02+0000) starting
1448802719: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1448802719: |-- *** auth-plug: startup
1448802719: |-- ** Configured order: mysql

1448802719: |-- }}}} MYSQL
1448802719: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8880.
1448802719: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 8880.
1448802719: Opening websockets listen socket on port 8881.
1448802719: New connection from ****** on port 8880.
1448802719: |-- mosquitto_auth_unpwd_check(******)
1448802719: |-- ** checking backend mysql
1448802719: |-- getuser(******) AUTHENTICATED=1 by mysql
1448802719: New client connected from ****** as ****** (c1, k15, u'******').
1448802719: Sending CONNACK to ****** (0, 0)
```

Whenever I try connecting with the HiveMQ Websockets Client it does a timeout...

Can someone give me an indication of how to achieve this? Help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Pedro.

**UPDATE: managed to connect by importing CA certificate**

I have since managed to connect to mosquito using the Paho MQTT client for javascript! I made slight changes to *mosquitto.conf*:

```
listener 8880
protocol mqtt

listener 8881
protocol websockets
cafile /home/hi/cert/ca.crt
certfile /home/hi/cert/hi.com.crt
keyfile /home/hi/cert/hi.com.key
tls_version tlsv1
#require_certificate false
```

The issue I have now is that I'm only able to connect if I have imported the *hi.com.crt* file and manually set to "Always Trust" on keychain (OS X). Since the certificate is self-signed and not trusted by iOS i can't login using my iPhone...

Shouldn't the default mosquitto TLS behavior be NOT to require the certificate from the client side?

Comment: Do you get any error messages or any other output in the moquitto log? Also have you tried the Paho websocket client?

Comment: I've been using the Paho MQTT lib for javascript and also get timeouts when trying to connect using TLS. I've added the verbose mosquitto output to my original post. It seems to me that mosquitto isn't even trying to load the cretificates... Thanks!

Comment: What does hi-server resolve to? If it resolves to 127.0.0.1 that would explain things

Comment: The certificates where generated using the generator script from J-P Mens (https://github.com/owntracks/tools/blob/master/TLS/generate-CA.sh) so after a quick inspection it does seem that they are pointing to 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments it sounds like hi-server resolves to 127.0.0.1/localhost. This means that the line in the config that says

```
bind_address hi-server
```

Tells mosquitto to only listen for websocket connections on localhost not any of the public interfaces.

Comment this line out and try again

Comment: As root please run lsof -i :8881 this will show what interfaces mosquitto is listening on

Comment: I have made progress! Still have some minor issues though (check edit on main post)

Comment: There is not client cert here, it is just a case of getting iOS to trust the server's certificate, you should be able to import ca.crt rather than the hi.server.crt and then iOS will trust all servers signed by that cert

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did the trick. I am now able to access mosquitto via TLS from my iPhone.